# Android Studio public object arraylist (object database)

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm making a game on Android Studio and it will have all sorts of items with their own values. I need to make a list of objects which can be modified from other classes. For example, I have class Tool and I want to make a list of Tool objects which I can modify from other classes.

**This is what I've got so far:**

```
 public void StartGame() {
    ArrayList<Tool> tools = new ArrayList<>(); //ID, Name, Owned, Fight, Resource, Building, Crafting, Clothing
    tools.add(new Tool(1,"Hatchet",false,2,0,0,0,0));
    tools.add(new Tool(2,"Pocket Knife",false,0,0,0,0,0));
}
```

For now I can create all the items when I start the game and modify the list from within the StartGame() itself. But what I want to achieve is that whenever the game starts I set all the list items value owned = false and whenever I need to, I can modify them once again.

Comment: use flag to check items you want to  modify or not.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Utils` class like this.

```
public class Utils{
    public static List<Tools> myList;

    public static List<Tools> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public static void setMyList(List<Tools> myList) {
        test.myList = myList;
    }
    public static void changeLogic(){
        //change ligic
    }
}
```

and use Utils class where ever you want

```
Utils.setList(myList);
```